# Replacing all constant factors in expressions by +1

Tags: replacement

I have expressions like 
$a - b + c(d-\frac12 e) + \frac{f-i g}{h}$
where $i$ is the imaginary number. I would like to remove all minus signs (and if possible, also get rid of constants such as $\frac12$ or $i$, to obtain 
$a + b + c(d+e) + \frac{f+g}{h}$.

Is there a way to do this in mathematica? My attempts at defining a suitable replacement rule have not succeeded so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that your question boils down to replacing all numerical multiplicative factors with 1, which is directly implemented as

```
exp = a - b + (f - I g)/h + c (d - e/2); 
exp //. {Times[pre___, n_?NumericQ, post___] :> Times[pre, post]}

(* a + b + c (d + e) + (f + g)/h *)
```

I've tested this on a number of different cases and it seems pretty robust.

Comment: Please see my answer intended as a complement to your own.

Comment: Thanks, this worked nicely!

Answer (score 7):

**Update:** A variant of @Daniel W's idea:

```
times = Times @@ DeleteCases[{##}, _?NumericQ] &;
numbersToOne = # /. Times -> times &;

numbersToOne[a - b + c (d - 1/2 e) + (f - g I)/Sqrt[h]]
```

> a + b + c (d + e) + (f + g)/h

```
numbersToOne[a - b + c (d Pi - 1/2 e) + (f E - g I)/Sqrt[h]]
```

> a + b + c (d + e) + (f + g)/Sqrt[h]

**Original answer:**

```
exp = a - b + (f  - I g)/h + c (d - e/2);
replaceNumbers = # /.  Power[a_, b_?NumericQ] :> Power[a, ToString[b, StandardForm]] /. 
     x_?NumericQ :> 1 /. s_String :> ToExpression[s] &

replaceNumbers @ exp
```

> a + b + c (d + e) + (f + g)/h

```
replaceNumbers @ (a - b + c (d Pi - 1/2 e) + (f E - g I)/Sqrt[h])
```

> a + b + c (d + e) + (f + g)/Sqrt[h]

Answer (score 3):

Another idea is to use [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect):

```
Collect[(a - b + c (d - 1/2 e) + (f - g I)/h), _Symbol, 1&]
```

> a + b + c (d + e) + f/h + g/h

Comment: I try to understand your tricky solution,  until now in vain. If I omit the third argument in `Collect[(a - b + c (d - 1/2 e) + (f - g I)/h), _Symbol, 1&]` it seems that the expression is unchanged. So what is the intention using `_Symbol` ? Thanks!

Comment: I gave  a comment, but forgot to address it to you. Hopefully it works now...

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to Daniel W's answer, due to the Attributes of `Times` his replacement may be greatly simplified as follows:

```
expr = -(7 I a π z)/(83 d);  (* just an example *)

expr /. x_*_?NumericQ :> x
```

> ```
> (a z)/d
> ```

Note:

- [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) is not needed.
- [`BlankNullSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html) is not used.
- The right-hand-side is simply `x`.

An illustration of the key attributes [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat.html), [`NumericFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericFunction.html), and [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html) using a head other than `Times`:

```
Attributes[foo] = {Flat, NumericFunction, Orderless};

foo @@ expr /. foo[x_, n_?NumericQ] :> {x, n}
```

> ```
> {foo[a, 1/d, z], foo[-((7 I)/83), π]}
> ```

Comment: I tried to simplify the pattern like you did, but did not think to set attributes.